# No module named middleware for django-bouncer

Tags: django

I'm using [django-bouncer](https://github.com/shelfworthy/django-bouncer) to make a waiting list in a Django 1.6 app. Unfortunately, when I add 'bouncer.middleware.MembersOnlyMiddleware' to my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES as required, I get: "ImportError: No module named middleware." I tried going into the Django shell and typing "from bouncer.middleware import MembersOnlyMiddleware," but that received the same error.

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: python --version and under dist-packages directory can you see this package? are you using linux? what is your distro?

Comment: It is 2.7.1. I'm on Mac OS X, 10.7.5.

Comment: run this command in your terminal , it will show you list of python directory. search in that directories for finding bouncer or django-bouncer. and tell us the result

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell you :) python -c "import site;print site.getsitepackages()"

Comment: No problem. I tried it inside the shell and got an invalid syntax error, and outside of the shell I got "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getsitepackages'." I ended up using this to get it: from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib
print(get_python_lib()). I opened the site-packages and I see "bouncer" and "bouncer-0.1.10-py2.7.egg-info" but nothing that starts with "django-bouncer."

Comment: Are you installed it via pip? I think you tried `pip install bouncer`.  did you tried `pip install django-bouncer` ?

Comment: Thanks! "pip install django-bouncer" did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django-bouncer` and `bouncer` are not the same package.

Try to install django-bouncer:

```
pip install django-bouncer
```